# Typescript reference 'this' type of an object

Tags: typescript

Consider the following type:

```js
type UserList = {
  userIds: string[]
  userData: {
    [UserId in UserList['userIds'][number]]: {
      userId: UserId
      username: string
    }
  }
}
```

with that I want to tell TypeScript compiler two things:

1. `userData` keys must exist in `userIds`
2. `userId` field must be equal to the key of the same entry

I feel that I need some kind of `this` or `self` keyword instead of `UserList`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe it's possible to refer to the exact string values inside `userIds` without resorting to using a generic type parameter:

```
type UserList<T extends ReadonlyArray<string>> = {
  userIds: T
  userData: {
    [UserId in T[number]]: {
      userId: UserId
      username: string
    }
  }
}
```

And your type definition would have to look as follows:

```
const a: UserList<['hello']> = {
    userIds: ['hello'],
    userData: {
        hello: {
            userId: 'hello',
            username: 'username'
        }
    }
}
```

If you don't want to specify the user IDs twice (inside the generic parameter and inside the actual `UserList` variable), you [have to use a wrapper function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66973498/typescript-generics-infer-object-property-type-without-a-function-call):

```
function asUserList<T extends ReadonlyArray<string>>(list: UserList<T>) {
  return list;
}

const a = asUserList({
    userIds: ['hello'] as const,
    userData: {
        hello: {
            userId: 'hello',
            username: 'username'
        }
    }
})
```

---

If you don't use a generic parameter and instead try to use the `this` type inside an interface like this:

```
interface UserList {
  userIds: string[]
  userData: {
    [UserId in this['userIds'][number]]: {
      userId: UserId
      username: string
    }
  }
}
```

It wouldn't work because `this['userIds']` would always resolve to the weak `string[]` type, not a specific set of strings that would allow you to strongly type `userData` based on the exact value of `userIds`.