# Dynamic typing on the basis on each array element

Tags: typescript

I have some extensions:

```
type ExtensionOptions = { name: string }

type BoldOptions = ExtensionOptions & { boldShortcut?: string }
type ItalicOptions = ExtensionOptions & { italicShortcut?: string }
type LinkOptions = ExtensionOptions & { autoLink?: boolean }

declare class Extension {
    constructor(options: ExtensionOptions)
}

declare class BoldExtension extends Extension {
  isSelectionBold: boolean
  constructor(options: BoldOptions)
}

declare class ItalicExtension extends Extension {
  isSelectionItalic: boolean
  constructor(options: ItalicOptions)
}

declare class LinkExtension extends Extension {
  isSelectionLink: boolean
  constructor(options: LinkOptions)
}
```

I want to create an Array type so that I can pass Tuple with extension and it's options with intellisense. For example:

```
// Generic type. It works but without intellisense
type Extensions = Array<[Extension, ExtensionOptions]>

const extensions = [
  [BoldExtension, { name: 'italic' }],
  [ItalicExtension, { name: 'italic' }],
  [LinkExtension, { name: 'link', autoLink: true }] // Need intellisense for LinkExtension here
]
```

I tried to do some experiments:

```
type Extensions<T> = Array<[
  T,
  T extends new (...args: infer Options) => any
    ? Options[0] // we know that first argument is the `options`
    : never
]>
```

Here's the [TypeScript playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAogHsCA7AzgSwPZIPJmJ1KAXigG8okBDAWwgC4oVgAnNJAcygF8AoH0SFABCGADYATXPiwpisBMnRYpBWQDIyUAEZjxAZQAWGZsADGAV2AB+Bk1Ydu-cNACSwSqLSmVMufESoBD6EGuRo7p6mhsZmljaMLGycvALQADJsANbBsiT+ikF4qlChUJSWGBlImfE6YhCUSI484hCmopTM0O2UKLL5gVhkPFBQpjIs5qbAxgAUGEUyDANKOIuoAJQ8vC1tHV1jHX3CuisEUBAKSOL9V6vDo2goehCibdJIIhIMdW+NI2MJswpjNmPN1igGF9JBCtjtWj0Dj1jm4PF4zkNLgEbvIAvdSACni83tMCKjIj8MPV-qNxqhJtM5gsPpCoOSvDk4XwEftukdZFVMhimljkDjhQ8oETXu8CILKdSkAC6XYQUyIQxBZztnwAPS6qAAFWcUAAjDx9VBUriCr4SABBZjMSggAA8AG1hQAaG2DNYsgC6AD49QbjYIAExOQTClCuw1BuSO51u90Aw1e9MXK44pAQADuUFmADpS512Ky2AAzCDMKCc4iJxogAGjKz1iHugAMAaglvz0EySAwheABkowCgVbQzCYZWY7HMtCQk6eVoM0AABszVJvW1AGHmAG61njBvgqyeiv2s2Ou4WJkhp0ajd2C72aKi0BgAck81R-H1yhmeUrWBaAuADH1LXCH9ZGPWsoA3A5GnEKUV1eTwUEUaBxAwCAUCQH9J3zYxMjPHggA) if you want to have a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no (simple) specific `ExtensionPair` type in TypeScript that meets your needs.  It should be a two-element [tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) where the first element is a one-argument [construct signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#construct-signatures) producing *some* `Extension` instance, and where the second element is the type of its argument.  That connection between the two elements requires [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) to express.  If TypeScript had [*existentially* quantified generics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#Existential_types) (as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#14466](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14466)) then you could express that "some" in a way that makes `ExtensionPair` a specific type.  But it doesn't, so we need to make it a regular generic (which is *universally* quantified, meaning "all" and not "some"):

```
type ExtensionPair<T extends new (arg: any) => Extension> = 
  [T, ConstructorParameters<T>[0]];
```

And if you have an *array* or *tuple* of those, you need to have a corresponding array or tuple of type arguments.  You can write that as a [mapped array/tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays) (a mapped type over the keys of a generic tuple/array type will only iterate over the number-like indices and will produce another tuple/array type; see the previous link):

```
type ExtensionPairs<T extends (new (arg: any) => Extension)[]> = 
  { [I in keyof T]: ExtensionPair<T[I]> }
```

It can be annoying to write out a type like this, since you'll be forced to specify some redundant information:

```
const extensions: ExtensionPairs<[
  typeof BoldExtension,
  typeof ItalicExtension,
  typeof LinkExtension
]> = [
    [BoldExtension, { name: 'italic' }],
    [ItalicExtension, { name: "" }],
    [LinkExtension, { name: "a", autoLink: true }]
  ];
```

It would be nice if the compiler could just *infer* such a type, but TypeScript doesn't have that ability directly (see [Typescript generics, infer object property type without a function call](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66973498/2887218) ).  Instead you could write a generic helper function, since TypeScript *can* infer type arguments for generic function calls:

```
function asExtensionPairs<T extends (new (arg: any) => Extension)[]>(
  arr: [...ExtensionPairs<T>]) {
  return arr;
}
```

And use it:

```
const extensions = asExtensionPairs([
  [BoldExtension, { name: 'italic' }],
  [ItalicExtension, { name: "" }],
  [LinkExtension, { name: "a", autoLink: true }]
]);
/* const extensions: [
    ExtensionPair<typeof BoldExtension>, 
    ExtensionPair<typeof ItalicExtension>, 
    ExtensionPair<typeof LinkExtension>
  ] */
```

That produces the same value with the same type (it's displayed a little differently but it is the same type) without requiring that you write it out the type yourself.

It also has the advantage of giving you autosuggest/IntelliSense from partial input, and errors if you get something wrong:

```
const oops = asExtensionPairs([
  [BoldExtension, { name: "a", autoLink: true }], // error, 
  // autoLink is an excess property
])
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAogHsCA7AzgSwPZIPJmJ1KAXigG8okBDAWwgC4oVgAnNJAcygF8AoH0SFABCGADYATXPiwpisBMnRYpBWQDIyvAdACSwSqLQBjFTLnxEqAqcIbSW8NAAybANY3ZJC4ut5VUOyhKAFdgDBckVwB+BgAjDDEISiRuPnEII1FKZmhMyhRZbyssMh4oKCMZFmCjMOYACgw-GQYRCQ8ASh5eHnS8nIqsguExcSKlFIgFJHFC6YnS8rgGJGDqWIhmAG4yiqrmGrrG5tRW0c7utIysgbzhvQNjcYIoKctZ+UsF0l2QFbWNttdpVUNVahgGk1pKcoA9DCYTiguj0+jdckNZBFXM8Sm9kB8cSkfuUAF7-dabHblEFMA7gyGIhhYi49bSfHxYAAKlDQzAAPAAVV7TD5ICAAdyg9Wy7AYyRAHWIAD52cUkCqSABtAUAGigAGF9ocIdzmDQIIhmChBUrNQAGAC6Dp2-Ecqom3N51qFeJmsnqYsl0uYsqCSAVyvdBA6modGrIUE1OigbCgrggIAwADMoAKHQxCZ7+QKk3HUjwqLQUGBKEZoABZZLBAyLPag4VfVQF+YEIvWzW7crabMjCSEnWDqDDnNwp49rAT8pDxwjrGE3ZlrWT8qatpjedIPXkSv0KAAcjQ+nhZ+4DsXS53s6M44TJ4YACJ37f7w-NWuD0eFDmh+lDvnqIRhFiDDVNAXAOpOzqXDwWbBEgtQvPkhY8lagodvi-qBlKMpyuGipECqhIxnG9S7NkzAMJqAB0zFYV6NoOoqxJQDkwDBMwKR0TsPQ0sAeFqp4QQoKxVr1AOO57i+x7Aeel6PEYN5wfeSZXnOnYLq+ymft+ux-m4ilAbQIFgUEoThG40EHLB8EcTsAD0ABUbZMGJEwoAxk7SXy06jvuenqnqAUHkWQUrjOOnPgeSoRQ+gXBf+YVKhuUDua5fA8CJUAJGAEmYVF2EoLJJkKQBBmWVA76geBtlQVOjnflArmua8zDMBCACEPAcUAA)